# C# Timer Event not firing off

Tags: c#, events, timer

I can't get the timer to tick every time when i create a new **command object** I am wondering what is causing this. I am new to C# so if i could get help as to why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated.

**This should trigger, but doesnt**

```
command Cmd = new command("!example", 10);
```

Here's the code.

```
public class Timeout
{
    public Timeout() { }
    public static List<command> timeouts = new List<command>();
    public class command
    {
        public string cmd;
        public int seconds;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
        public command(string cmd, int seconds)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("created, " + cmd + ", " + seconds);
            this.cmd = cmd;
            this.seconds = seconds;
            this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);           
            timer.Start();
        }
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("tick -> " + seconds);
            if (seconds > 0)
                seconds--;
            else
            {
                timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
                timeouts.Remove(this);
                Debug.WriteLine("removed");
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: prove this: "I can't get the timer to tick every time"

Comment: Well, as you have written **timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;** in your tick event, this removes the method association with the delegate and after first time, you will never get a tick event.

Comment: Set `timer.Enabled = true;`

Comment: timer ticks for `second` times. after that it removes the handler. everything looks fine. also it is better to call `timer.Stop()` after removing the tick handler @RohitPrakash

Comment: calling `timer.Start()` sets `timer.Enabled` true. @Reniuz

Comment: @dotctor You are right I missed Start call

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is specialized timer to run as a form component. Perhaps you do something what makes this timer not working properly. Use `System.Timers.Timer` instead.

Comment: @doctor, as per his calls and code implementation
**command Cmd = new command("!example", 10);** tick event would be triggered 10 times, before it removes the handler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

actually you can do this way.
call the timer once you create the object

```
command cmd =new command("!example",10);
//then am calling the timer event
timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);
//_timer_Elapsed is the event name
timer.Enabled = true;

public static void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
//do something here
}
```

please find the link [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer) for more reference.hope my comment helps you :)